# Is there a way to identify the current index within a map/forEach

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart

Most languages provide something like this `apples.map((apple, index) => {})`. What would be Dart's equivalent of identifying the index within a map or forEach?

Someone has offered `apples.asMap().map((apple, index) => {})` however that returns an unmodifiable version of the map, which is not suitable when I'm trying to map a list to produce widgets `.toList()` inside `children:` of a `Column`.

Comment: `.asMap` is the proper way to go. Map, filter, reduce and so on are functional-like tools. They do not modify the original structure, and that's by design. Instead, they return a copy of the original structure. If you need modified elements, just keep the return value of `asMap`.

Answer (score 2):

One way to use the index and value of a list item is to use the new [collection for](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour?source=post_page---------------------------#collection-operators) construct. The code would look something like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final list = ['Mango', 'Orange', 'Apple'];

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
          ListTile(title: Text('${list[i]} has index $i')),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

For this to work you'll need to update your minimum Dart SDK version in your `pubspec.yaml` like so:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.3.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go, I've ended up just creating a separate for loop outside and adding all the widgets to a ist to be used as a child. This might look cleaner. Cheers

Comment: These new constructs are part of Dart’s UI as Code philosophy and are recommended a well. If my answer serves your purpose, can you mark it as the right answer?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure I entirely understand what you're trying to do, but `map` and `forEach` are defined on Iterable, and the elements of an Interable aren't necessarily ordered, so providing an index for each element doesn't necessarily make sense. For example, if the Iterable is a Set then the elements have no order.

I don't quite get why you need the index in your particular example.  If you expand your example, maybe I'll understand.

Comment: Having an index in a `map` could be useful for numerous reasons that have nothing to do with the actual index of the item in the original list. E.G. : knowing how many items have been seen previously to the current one, creating auto-increment IDs, knowing if the current item is at an even or odd index, etc.